# Control that uses "Color" type dependency property

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, dependency-properties, controltemplate

I'm trying to write a Button control that displays a background gradient, starting with a color specified by a custom property, and ending with a hard-coded color.  Seems to me this should be a straightforward control template, but I can't get it to work.

Subclassed "Button" with a `Color` dependency property:

```
public class GradientButton : Button
{
    public Color BackgroundColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(BackgroundColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BackgroundColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BackgroundColor", typeof(Color), typeof(GradientButton), new PropertyMetadata((sender, args) => {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Set bg col");
        }));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(GradientButton), null);
    public GradientButton()
        : base()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(GradientButton);
    }
}
```

Control template, which sets a background gradient using the `BackgroundColor` DP:

```
<Style TargetType="custom:GradientButton">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="200" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="custom:GradientButton">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                            <GradientStop Color="{TemplateBinding BackgroundColor}" Offset="0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="1" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Grid.Background>

                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding BackgroundColor}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

If I use the control like this:

```
<custom:GradientButton Text="Foo" BackgroundColor="#FF0000" />
```

then I expect to see a button with red-to-gray background gradient.  Instead, only the gray part of the gradient appears:

[image: Control does not show the red part of the background]

What painfully obvious thing am I missing?

---

**Edit** For emphasis:

1. I added "Text" DP to prove my DP / TemplateBinding is in fact kosher.
2. Note that I can't display the "BackgroundColor", even as text in a text block -- and yet I have confirmed in the debugger that it *is in fact being set on the control*.

Comment: You have four `GradientStop` properties and no `GradientStart` ones?  Just a guess - I'm not familiar with it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for making confuse. My answer is not correct. The issue here is TemplateBinding. TemplateBinding is a lightwight binding at compile time while using TemplatedParent happens at runtime, thus TemplateBinding has some limitation, one of which is it cannot bind to Freezables. What you can do is to use traditional templated parent instead:

```
<GradientStop Color="{Binding Path=BackgroundColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Offset="0" />
```

You can refer to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/liviuc/archive/2009/12/14/wpf-templatebinding-vs-relativesource-templatedparent.aspx

"You'd think the compiler or the runtime would throw some kind of error, but apparently not."

A good point. I did not see any binding error either in output window. However, I used Snoop to look into Color property and found exactly what I expected:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=BackgroundColor; DataItem=null; target element is 'GradientStop' (HashCode=4605357); target property is 'Color' (type 'Color')

Comment: Sorry -- I meant to say, `GradientStop` is a DependencyObject, so it should be usable in bindings, no?

Comment: You are exactly right. I edited my answer. Sorry for the incorrect answer!

Comment: Ah, that would explain it ... so I can't use TemplateBinding to target a `Color` property because it's a Freezable (which doesn't exist in Silverlight, but something analagous, I guess).  You'd think the compiler or the runtime would throw some kind of error, but apparently not.  Anyway, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

No problem,

Your first issue is how you're declaring your Gradient. The way you currently have will show a solid line of Red (or whatever color specified) for the top half, and a solid line of Gray for the bottom half. You want something like this and it does the rest of it for you.

```
<LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
     <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0"/>
     <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

Also, you could make this easier on yourself and just utilize properties already existent that are there for purposes just like this one so you don't need any additional code. Like the `Tag` Property (which personally I stuff all sorts of different crap into for different purposes depending on the instances. So something like this will also suffice just fine without the need for the extra dependency declarations (unless it really matters that's called "BackgroundColor");

```
<Style TargetType="custom:GradientButton">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="200" />
    <Setter Property="Tag" Value="Red"/><!-- For the sake of having a default -->

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="custom:GradientButton">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                             <GradientStop Color="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Offset="0"/>
                             <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Grid.Background>

                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and that should do ya up nicely, hope this helps. :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be `BackgroundColor` and not `Tag`?

Comment: @McAden It would be if he wanted to use all that additional code he wrote to specify that particular custom dependency property. Otherwise `Tag` already exists and you can pass just about whatever you want through it and doesn't require anything more than just his template.

Comment: I would assume that's what he wanted, otherwise why use `TargetType="custom:GradientButton"`?

Comment: I imagine there's more to the overall usage than just making a custom Button Template, but that's the OP's business. This is just an easier route for whatever he needs it for with no code behind necessary at least for this little bit of his requirement....that is unless it absolutely has to have that specific Dependency Property in lieu of just using an existing Framework element already at his disposal to accomplish the same effect. Just trying to be helpful amigo. ;)

Comment: I tried your changes, but they don't affect anything.  There seems to be something really strange going on with the `Color` type -- see my edit to the question, and the "answer" that I posted.

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered a workaround:  if, instead of `TemplateBinding`, I use a `RelativeSource` binding, then my button renders as you would expect:

```
Color="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=custom:GradientButton},Path=BackgroundColor}"
```

Of course, this makes nary a whit of sense.  I'm convinced that this is a bug (or at least one of those things that *man was not meant to know*).

Comment: Hizaah! As long as ya got your remedy. AncestorType has been a pain in the a$$ for me in everything SL so far below 5 so definitely +1

Comment: @ChrisW. ha, thanks.  Still, I defy anyone to explain this to me ... actually I might start a bounty.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be specifying a direct path to find your property within the datacontext it needs? Otherwise Dude, I quit questioning the small stuff a long time ago...haha not worth the effort in some cases.